# Decrypting Gorilla Sessions Cookie Data

Tags: go, gorilla

Firstly, let me preface by saying I'm taking part in a Capture the Flag contest and I'm having some difficulty with a question related to Go Gorilla Sessions. I've never coded in Go, so this is fun, and frustrating :)

I have a secret key. I have an encoded Cookie. I need to decode the cookie, using the secret key I have, edit whatever data is in there, and re-encrypt with my altered data to progress in the challenge.

I've read the Gorilla Sessions Package documentation and not really getting any help.

Can anyone assist, where do I start?

Comment: Have you looked at the Codec implementation in the `securecookie` library used by Gorilla session? https://github.com/gorilla/securecookie/blob/master/securecookie.go

Comment: thanks, I had but initially dismissed it as the hint on the challenge told me to look at Gorilla Sessions as opposed to SecureCookie. It makes sense to use that package though, so thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs - gorilla provides a [secure cookie package](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/securecookie). 
Depending on your apps architecture - a basic implementation could work as follows:

Create a session management package to be used by your app. For the sake of example - lets call it `sessionmngr`

Inside of `sessionmngr`,  import `"github.com/gorilla/securecookie"`.

In the `sessionmngr` package, use a lower case `init()` function to set up a private instance of `securecookie`. Once a package is imported, lowercase init() functions are called in the order they are declared. (Check out the language [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization) for more info). You will use this instance to encode and decode cookies from the standard library's `http.Request`.

```
import (
    "github.com/gorilla/securecookie"      

    //you will need this later
    "http" 
)

//declare private secure cookie 
var s *securecookie.SecureCookie

//initialize it here (taken from the gorilla docs example)
func init() {
    var hashKey = []byte("very-secret")
    var blockKey = []byte("a-lot-secret")
    s = securecookie.New(hashKey, blockKey)
}
```

You will then use `s` throughout the package in functions that need to encode and decode the a cookie's value. The [securecookie package documentation](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/securecookie) provides a boilerplate example.

To meet the requirements of reading and modifying an already encrypted cookie - use the `Decode` and `Encode` methods on the instance of `securecookie` that was setup in the example above.

Something Like ---

```
func DecodeAndModify(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //get reference to cookie if set
    if cookie, err := r.Cookie("cookie-name"); err == nil {

        value := make(map[string]string)
        //use Decode to get the value from the cookie
        if err = s.Decode("cookie-name", cookie.Value, &value); err == nil {
            //modify the value in some way
            value["newKey"] = "newValue"
            //re-encode it
            if encoded, err := s.Encode("cookie-name", value); err == nil {
                cookie := &http.Cookie{
                    Name:  "cookie-name",
                    Value: encoded,
                    Path:  "/",
                }
                http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Syllabix, appreciate the detailed answer. I believe this is exactly what I need, therefore marking the answer as correct, with thanks.